# Question on Counting Methods

Tags: permutations, combinations

What are the number of ways of selecting 5 different numbers from the numbers 1 through 55?

Comment: You should probably read some basics on combinatorics, at least take a look at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

Answer (score 2):

To have 5 distinct numbers from 55 numbers, it would be 55C5 or ${55 \choose 5}$ = 3 478 761

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether different orderings count as another "way" of arranging the numbers.  If different orderings count

$$^{55}P_{5}=\frac{55!}{(55-5)!}=417451320$$

If different orderings of the same 5 numbers do not count as another "way" of arranging the numbers then the answer is

$$^{55}C_{5}=\frac{55!}{5!\times(55-5)!}=3478761$$

as the previous poster suggested.  Dividing by $5!$ accounts for the fact there will be $5$ times as many permutations as there are combinations since there are $5!$ ways of arranging each combination of 5 distinct numbers.